# What should I increase Xmx setting to for IntelliJ 9.04?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, memory-management

I'm getting out of memory issues when I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.4, build IU-95.627.

My Macbook Pro has 4GB of Memory

I've heard one recommendation clearing out the ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJ90 folder is an answer..
Is that something others would recommend?

What should I set it to?
I saw this [post](http://leshazlewood.com/2007/08/01/intellij-idea-on-mac-os-x-setting-java-vm-options/) and tried setting EXE4J_JAVA_HOME in my ~/.profile but that did't make a difference.

I've heard others say setting this too high is not a good idea as well..

Any ideas?
IntelliJ Contents/info.plist VMOptions setting:
-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -ea -Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar

PS: Just in case this has any bearing on things, I've been trying to use [Sqlprofiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlprofiler/) at the same time with a Grails app using the [p6spy plugin](http://www.grails.org/p6spy+plugin) in my IDE.

Comment: I wish the stack overflow guys could let me know why my content could not be posted. It ended up being an efreedom url.. Took me an age to figure that out. Much trial and error. Thinking it was images that were the issue initially...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but especially since you're working on a Grails app, you should try the new IntelliJ IDEA X. Lots of improvements for Grails development.

Comment: This IDE (v. 9) will not stop running out of memory. It doesn't matter how much I give it. I am at wits' end with this piece of junk.

Answer (score 1):

I usually increase -Xmx to 800m

```
-Xmx800m
```

No other changes. I don't have any problems with that in any of my projects, some of them Grails projects. Lately I have followed the EAP versions, and now I use IDEA X.

(I also have a MacBook Pro, three years old, but with 6GB RAM)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out this was down to looking up a huge stacktrace.log file in the target folder.
I didn't realise how huge it was until I looked at it in the Finder window....